# Starting with Python on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am starting to learn how to make Python project on AppEngine.
I have really hard time to find some good study resources.

I would like to see some example projects, which are updated for the last version of AppEngine.
I have really the basic knowledge of python, what are the best resources to understand python more deeply ?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101 for Python basics & https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253 for Web Dev in App Engine (GAE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether your question is about learning python or about learning app engine, but I'll give you a suggestion anyway.

If you have basic knowledge of python, the Udacity Web Development course may be pretty close to what you're looking for. Its goal is to teach web development - not app engine per se - but it uses app engine and you see many code examples, in addition to creating some of your own. If you've already been involved in web development for a bit it may be too elementary for you, but you can always skip lessons if you want.

Edit: 
If you're looking for something more, I'd advise you to simply go through the [App Engine Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/). They're intuitive, straight from the source and do a good job explaining how it all works. Want to make sure your python is up to par? Check out the [Python Tutorials](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/index.html). You can go through them pretty quickly and they give you a pretty solid background.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Thanks. I probably should have posted the links.

Comment: The course looks really nice, but I am looking for something more advanced. I dont need to learn basics of web development. I was developing long time in PHP.

Comment: @VojtechVrbka I edited my answer. Sorry if I didn't help you :) Good luck!